# Data structure for set of (non-disjoint) sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that roughly corresponds to (in Java terms) `Map<Set<int>, double>`. Essentially a set of sets of labeled marbles, where each set of marbles is associated with a scalar. I want it to be able to efficiently handle the following operations:

- Add a given integer to every set.
- Remove every set that contains (or does not contain) a given integer, or at least set the associated double to 0.
- Union two of the maps, adding together the doubles for sets that appear in both.
- Multiply all of the doubles by a given double.
- Rarely, iterate over the entire map.

under the following conditions:

- The integers will fall within a constrained range (between 1 and 10,000 or so); the exact range will be known at compile-time.
- Most of the integers within the range (80-90%) will never be used, but which ones will not be easily determinable until the end of the calculation.

  - The number of integers used will almost always still be over 100.
- Many of the sets will be very similar, differing only by a few elements.
- It may be possible to identify certain groups of integers that frequently appear only in sequential order: for example, if a set contains the integers 27 and 29 then it (almost?) certainly contains 28 as well.

  - It may be possible to identify these groups prior to running the calculation.
  - These groups would typically have 100 or so integers.

I've considered tries, but I don't see a good way to handle the "remove every set that contains a given integer" operation.

The purpose of this data structure would be to represent discrete random variables and permit addition, multiplication, and scalar multiplication operations on them. Each of these discrete random variables would ultimately have been created by applying these operations to a fixed (at compile-time) set of independent Bernoulli random variables (i.e. each takes the value 1 or 0 with some probability).

The systems being modeled are *close* to being representable as a time-inhomogeneous Markov chains (which would of course simplify this immensely) but, unfortunately, it is essential to track the duration since various transitions.

Comment: It sounds like you know what you want already. What language will you be using? Java? There's no reason you can't go ahead and start implementing your suggested data structure and seeing what you like and don't like about it (in terms of insert/update/delete/other ops)

Comment: That's a good point and may be what I end up doing. The main reason I haven't yet is that the project is really only in the speculative stages right now. If there's no way to do this without it being agonizingly slow then I may just go for a much less ambitious design at the cost of expressiveness.

Regarding language, probably some combination of C# and F#.

Comment: Can you characterize the most common operations first? We might be able to optimize your data structure for those operations (the common case).

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate over the entire map"? Is that operation allowed to be linear in the total size of the map, as in, the cumulative size of all integer sets?

Comment: Have you considered a Hash for a Set, followed by `Map<Hash<Int>, double>` ? Since 80%-90% of the integers are never used, it seems you could get away with using a small number of bins (alleviating the only real issue with a hash, the memory consumption)

Comment: @AndyG: the most common operations will be scalar multiplication (which I don't expect to be difficult), followed by RV-multiplication (which corresponds to "add a given integer to every set" or "remove every set that contains a given integer").

Comment: @NiklasB. At the end of the calculation I'm going to want to take the expected value of the final discrete random variable, and I expect to do this by just iterating over every (set,scalar) pair and multiplying the scalar by the product of probabilities. It is OK if that last bit is slow as long as doesn't end up being slower than all the work done to get to that point.

Comment: @dhrumeel: yes, that would be the most straightforward way to do it. I'm a little concerned that it will be really horribly slow and am hoping there is some well-known existing data structure for this problem that I just haven't heard of.

Comment: "Add a given integer to every set." Can it happen that an integer is already iside some sets but not others? Or will it always be a whole new element?

Comment: @NiklasB. it could already be inside some sets but not others. (e.g. "A * (A * B + B) = 2 * A * B")

Comment: At least the "add to every set" and "multiply every scalar" could be handled by one member set/double of the map that will only be evaluated when there is a need for it; lazily, so to speak. Maybe keeping that in mind, you can focus on optimizing the other operations? What kind of complexities are you going for, space and time?

Comment: Adding to @G.Bach's suggestion, if you can support the operation "find set" reasonably fast (which you can maybe do by keeping a map Int -> Set, combined with a linear search), you can also merge two maps fast by using merge-by-weight. Just evaluate the smaller map completely (resolve the laziness) and insert the sets from the smaller one by one into the larger one. An argument why this is fast can be found [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22725/merge-by-weight-to-solve-reachability-problems-in-trees-and-dags).

Comment: Generally, there's a problematic case when you perform "add to every set" or "remove from every set" and it causes two formerly distinct sets to become equal (in which case you want to merge the two). I guess you can also resolve this lazily

Comment: How are you generating these very-similar sets? How many sets are there on average? How large are the sets on average?

As an aside, rather than a `Map<Set<int>, double>`, you might want to consider just subclassing `Set<int>` and adding a `Weight` field.

Comment: @Andy OP doesn't even use Java. I think he or she is  more interested in a good conceptual approach

Comment: @NiklasB. It should work in any OO language, including C#. In functional languages, the equivalent would be a type extension. I realise it's not what the OP was explicitly looking for, which is why I only mentioned it as an aside.

Comment: @AlexGodofsky in Java you can write a class `class MySet { private TreeSet<Integer> set; private Double w; .. }` and implement what you need as functions .. good luck

Comment: First, let's clarify things a bit and label them properly so that it is clear what is what. The sample space S is unknown, however we have T={X_1,...X_n} independent Bernoulli variables that are defined on S (where n <= 10000). Correct?

What are the probabilities of those Bernoulli variables becoming 1, are they all the same?? What is a Random Variable (the big one) here, is it a single Map<Set<int>, double>? Is it ok to define it as a function RV from P({1..n}) to double, where P(Y) denotes the powerset of Y? For a given set Y: do we consider RV(Y)=0 and Y not present in the Map equivalent?

Comment: How do you define RV multiplication? Like this? : (RV_1*RV_2)(Y) = RV_1(Y)*RV_2(Y) If yes, then it corresponds to finding an intersection of the two Maps (i.e.: find the Set<int>s Y which are present in both), and then multiplying the corresponding doubles. Why do you say that it corresponds to "add a given integer to every set" or "remove every set that contains a given integer"? What about "Remove every set that does not contain a given integer"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a data structure, that can do all of your operations pretty efficiently:

I'm going to refer to it as a **BitmapArray** for this explanation.

Thinking about it, apparently **for just the operations you have described** a sorted array with bitmaps as keys and weights(your doubles) as values will be pretty efficient.

The bitmaps are what maintain membership in your set. Since you said the range of integers in the set are between 1-10,000, we can maintain information about any set with a bitmap of length 10,000.

It's gonna be tough sorting an array where the keys can be as big as 2^10000, but you can be smart about implementing the comparison function in the following way:

- Iterate from left to right on the two bitmaps
- XOR the bits on each index
- Say you get a 1 at ith position
- Whichever bitmap has 1 at ith position is greater
- If you never get a 1 they're equal

I know this is still a slow comparison. 
But not too slow, [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn2vh/3/)'s a benchmark fiddle I did on bitmaps with length 10000. 
This is in Javascript, if you're going to write in Java, it's going to perform even better.

```
    function runTest() {
    var num = document.getElementById("txtValue").value;
    num = isNaN(num * 1) ? 0 : num * 1;

    /*For integers in the range 1-10,000 the worst case for comparison are any equal integers which will cause the comparision to iterate over the whole BitArray*/
    bitmap1 = convertToBitmap(10000, num);
    bitmap2 = convertToBitmap(10000, num);

    before = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    var result = firstIsGreater(bitmap1, bitmap2, 10000);
    after = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    alert(result + " in time: " + (after-before) + " ms");

}


function convertToBitmap(size, number) {
    var bits = new Array();
    var q = number;
    do {
        bits.push(q % 2);
        q = Math.floor(q / 2);
    } while (q > 0);


    xbitArray = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        xbitArray.push(0);
    }

    var j = xbitArray.length - 1;
    for (var i = bits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        xbitArray[j] = bits[i];
        j--
    }
    return xbitArray;
}

function firstIsGreater(bitArray1, bitArray2, lengthOfArrays) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfArrays; i++) {
        if (bitArray1[i] ^ bitArray2[i]) {
            if (bitArray1[i]) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

document.getElementById("btnTest").onclick = function (e) {
    runTest();
};
```

Also, remember that you only have to do this once, when building your BitmapArray (or while taking unions) and then it's going to become pretty efficient for the operations you'd do most often:

**Note**: N is the length of the BitmapArray.

**Add integer to every set**: Worst/best case O(N) time. Flip a 0 to 1 in each bitmap.

**Remove every set that contains a given integer**: Worst case O(N) time.

- For each bitmap check the bit that represents the given integer, if 1 mark it's index.
- Compress the array by deleting all marked indices.

If you're okay with just setting the weights to 0 it'll be even more efficient. This also makes it very easy if you want to remove all sets that have any element in a given set.

**Union of two maps**: Worst case O(N1+N2) time. Just like merging two sorted arrays, except you have to be smart about comparisons once more.

**Multiply all of the doubles by a given double**: Worst/best case O(N) time. Iterate and multiply each value by the input double.

**Iterate over the BitmapArray**: Worst/best case O(1) time for next element.

Comment: Thanks! I had been musing about using a bitmap; right now I'm using a `Dictionary<MySet<int>,double>` where `MySet` is an immutable set implemented as an array of integers and supporting only the union and set equality operations. The sorted array of integers has similar asymptotic performance, but the bitmap should give a really big constant factor speedup. (Up to 32x!) I've been performance profiling my application and about 70% of its time is spent in the union operation.

Comment: Thinking about it, union is probably the hardest operation among the ones you mentioned and I think an O(N1+N2) time seems asymptotically optimal for ordered unions of any data structure. Let me know if you find any more constant factor speedups, which I guess are the only possible optimizations to the union operation, if order has to be maintained.

Comment: A heckuva lot of the unions involve one set being a proper subset of another, or involve just appending a few elements to the end of a chain. I got a huge speedup from detecting the former case (and in it, just returning the larger set w/o any new allocations).

My code is at the point where things like automatic array bounds checking and memory allocation are a pretty large fraction of the total runtime. I'm actually going to wrap some of the code in an `unsafe` block at some point to skip the bounds checks.